# Iterate through a bunch of numpy arrays stored as different variables

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to iterate through a series of numpy arrays whose variable names look like

```
numpy_array_001, numpy_array_002, ... numpy_array_N
```

To add them up, I'm looking for something like:

```
sum += "numpy_array_"+str(number)
```

The issue with the above is that `"num_pyarray_"+str(number)` becomes a string and is no longer an array, so that doesn't work.

How can I rewrite this last line to add the arrays together?

The expected outcome is

```
sum = numpy_array_001 + numpy_array_002+ ... + numpy_array_N
```

for any N

Comment: Why not put all these arrays in a list and then use `sum(arr.sum() for arr in list_of_arrays)`. Not sure what result you want given that you didn't include the inputs and the expected outcome.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the OP is asking. He has a bunch of variables with similar names (only the last three characters are different) and he wants to iterate over them in a loop to sum them up (or concatenate them, or whatever). I think the only way to do this is with `eval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I think you'll have to use the [`eval` function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval) for this.

Here's a simple example in which I have three variables (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`) and I add them up:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3

# Make an string containing the expression to evaluate
expr=''
for i in range(3):
  expr = expr + 'x' + str(i+1) + ' + '
expr = expr[0:-3] # remove the last ' + '

# Show the expression, and evaluate it
print(expr)
eval(expr)
```

You can adapt this to do `sum +=` instead. So something like:

```
for i in range(N):  
    eval('sum += numpy_array_' + '{:03}'.format(i+1)')
```

But really, if you have any control over this, you should design your program such that it *doesn't* store a bunch of arrays in separate variables like that. That's just making life difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a list and use a list comprehension:

```
all_arrays = [] # empty list

# you just append the arrays once you know them.
# no need to keep track of the name at all
all_arrays.append(array_001)
all_arrays.append(array_002)

sum_total = sum([np.sum(k) for k in all_arrays])
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what is intended? I intentionally posted it as a comment because the question is unclear on the expected outcome.

Comment: Not 100 %, but let's see what the OP thinks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you actually mean writing the Ellipsis in python code or do you mean that the OP should put them in the list manually? @Joe

Comment: No, no Ellipsis. I just copied it from the original post. The OP should put the list together manually.

Comment: This shifts the issue to: How can I create the list "all_arrays", given that the number of arrays N is not known in advance? I only know how to create it for strings, i.e., "numpy_array_001", but not numpy objects numpy_array_001

Answer (score 0):

If you put them in a dictionary then you can iterate as you like over them since the key will be a string

like `Dic = {"numpy_array_001" : numpy_array_001,....}`

then you do `sum += Dict["numpy_array_"+str(number)` ]

Comment: Wordy, but this is the best way of matching strings (variable names) with objects.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support variable variable names except when you use `eval` and `exec`. Both are not exactly recommended. And in this case you actually don't need them.

You can simply put all the arrays in a list and then iterate over that list:

```
list_of_arrays = [numpy_array_001, numpy_array_002, ..., numpy_array_N]
```

Then you can calculate the sum of all sums with a generator expression and the built-in `sum` function:

```
sum(arr.sum() for arr in list_of_arrays)
```

Or the element-wise sum:

```
res = list_of_arrays[0].copy()
for arr in list_of_arrays[1:]:
    res += arr
```

Or even simpler (but it will create more intermediate arrays):

```
sum(list_of_arrays)
```

---

In case you really want to avoid the `list` and use the variable names you could do it like this:

```
expression = '+'.join('numpy_array_{:0>3}'.format(i) for i in range(1, N+1))
res = eval(expression)
```

For example:

```
N = 3
numpy_array_001 = np.ones((3, 3))
numpy_array_002 = np.ones((3, 3))*2
numpy_array_003 = np.ones((3, 3))*3
expression = '+'.join('numpy_array_{:0>3}'.format(i) for i in range(1, N+1))
eval(expression)
# array([[ 6.,  6.,  6.],
#        [ 6.,  6.,  6.],
#        [ 6.,  6.,  6.]])
```

However having to use `eval` is a sign that you didn't choose the best approach. There are only a few cases where `eval` has to be used. But here you really should use a list or other container to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks, this shifts the issue to: How can I create the list "list_of_arrays", given that the number of arrays is not known in advance?

Comment: @FabriceSchlegel Depends on "how" you created the variables in the first place. Just create a list instead.